# Understanding python asyncio Protocol

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am lacking understanding on how Python asyncio and protocols are working.

Documentaion that seems relevant:
[`class asyncio.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.Protocol)
[`Protocol.eof_received()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.Protocol.eof_received)  state machine shows relevant transitions
[`AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete(future)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete)

Example code that is echo tcp client:

```
import asyncio

class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, loop):
        self.message = message.encode()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.write_data()

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}',len(data))
        self.write_data()

    def eof_received(self):
        print("eof")
        return True

    def write_data(self):
        print("write")
        self.transport.write(self.message)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        print('Stop the event loop')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
message = 'Hello World!'

coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, loop),
                              '127.0.0.1', 5676)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
print("done")
```

Output when connceted on echo server:

```
write
Data received: {!r} 12
write
done
```

From what I understand this should run until connection is closed.

From: [Connection callbacks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#connection-callbacks)

connection_made() and connection_lost() are called exactly once per successful connection. All other callbacks will be called between those two methods, which allows for easier resource management in your protocol implementation.

and from also state machine:

```
start 
-> connection_made
[-> data_received]*
[-> eof_received]?
-> connection_lost 
-> end
```

But, function `EchoClientProtocol.connection_lost` is never called and 
`loop.run_until_complete(coro)` terminates before Protocol completes.

Question is:
How to get coroutine/future that wraps protocol in a way that coroutine completes when end state of protocol is reached and loop.run_until_complete returns on such event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sraw's answer points out, `loop.create_connection` is a coroutine that returns as soon as it has created a transport/protocol pair. So you need to run another coroutine (or equivalent object) that will keep the event loop alive for interesting things to happen.

> how to run loop until protocol internal state reaches state end without explicitly closing loop

You don't necessarily need to close or stop the loop. If I'm following you correctly, you'd like to avoid an unsightly `run_forever`, instead writing something like:

```
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
transport.close()
loop.run_until_complete(protocol.wait_connection_lost())
```

While `wait_connection_lost()` indeed doesn't come with asyncio, you are providing the protocol implementation, so you can easily create one for your protocol:

```
class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    # your other methods are unchanged

    def __init__(self, message, loop):
        self.message = message.encode()
        self.__done = loop.create_future()

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        # the value passed to set_result will be transmitted to
        # run_until_complete(protocol.wait_connection_lost()).
        self.__done.set_result(None)

    # When awaited, resumes execution after connection_lost()
    # has been invoked on this protocol.
    def wait_connection_lost(self):
        return self.__done
```

Answer (score 4):

`loop.run_until_complete(coro)` returns `transport, protocol`.

So to triggle `connection_lost`, the connection should be closed either by server or client. So you need:

```
transport, _ = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
transport.close()
loop.run_forever()
print("done")
```

As you are not stoping loop in `connection_lost`, it will be blocked here forever.

BTW, `coro` returns when connection is connectted successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to run loop until protocol internal state reaches state end without explicitly closing loop.

Comment: No, there seems isn't an interface in `asyncio` for this.